# Reevaluate ng-attr

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my angular application I have a tabset from angular-ui and I use ng-attr like this:

```
ng-attr-justified="{{ crawledVideos.length > 10 ? 'true' : 'false'}}"
```

The crawledVideos list is empty at the start so this evaluates false at the start, but afterwards the list has values, but the attribute is not reevaluated, so it is still false.

Is there any way to reevaluate the expression or do it any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set some flag in your controller that you set to true once the `crawledVideos` list is initialized. And then you can render the tabset only after the first initialization of the list:

```
.controller('YourCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.crawledVideosInitialized = false;
    // ... initialize $scope.crawledVideos ....
    $scope.crawledVideosInitialized = true;
});
```

And then, in your view, add `ngIf` to the tabset:

```
<uib-tabset ng-if="crawledVideosInitialized" ng-attr-justified="{{ crawledVideos.length > 10 ? 'true' : 'false'}}">
    ......
</uib-tabset>
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't think of such an approach.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can bind the value for the 'justified' attribute with a model on your scope, because as you can see [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tabs/tabs.js#L103), it gets evaluated on the parent scope. In your case that will be the $scope where you use the tabs.